# how to update state to wait for a function to complete in React

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, setstate

I am developing a React functional component for a model CRUD operations, this component will render save and delete buttons on the model form, and I am trying to show a waiting indicator when the user clicks the save or delete button and hide the indicator when the process completes.

I am using the [material-ui](https://material-ui.com/) React components library, and for the waiting indicator I am using the Backdrop component.

the component props are the save and delete callbacks and set by the parent component.

I added a boolean state to show/hide this backdrop, but the waiting indicator is not showing as the setState in react is asynchronous. so how can I achieve this?

here is my component:

```
export default function ModelControls({onSave, onDelete}) {

    const [wait, setWait] = useState(false);

    const saveClick = () => {
        setWait(true);
        const retId = onSave();
        setWait(false);
        ...
    };

    return (
        <Container maxWidth={"xl"}>
            <Grid container spacing={2}>
                <Grid item xs={6}>
                    <Box display="flex" justifyContent="flex-end">
                        <Box component="span">
                            <Button size="small" color="primary" onClick={saveClick}>
                                <SaveIcon />
                            </Button>
                        </Box>
                    </Box>
                </Grid>
            </Grid>
            <Backdrop open={wait}>
                <CircularProgress color="primary" />
            </Backdrop>
        </Container>
    );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just make the function `async` and add `await` in front of the `save` function.

```
const saveClick = async () => {
  setWait(true);
  const retId = await onSave();
  setWait(false);
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @Dipansh, you inspired me to the following solution.

now the `onSave` callback from parent must return a promise object

```
const saveClick = () => {
    setWait(true);
    onSave().then((retId) => {
        ...
        setWait(false);
    });
};
```

this way it is working as needed.